# Shell: selecting matching text between two strings on different lines

Tags: bash, shell, awk, sed

I want to be able to select all text between two strings that are found on two lines. A few complicating specifics:

- One of these strings is simple text (e.g., "match me")
- One of these strings is the docstring symbol (""")
- These two strings will not be found at the start of the line (if you count whitespace)

E.g.,

```
      match me: XXXXX
         I want this
         I want this
         I want this
     """
```

I would ideally like to

1. get the text between the two strings,
2. remove the whitespace and
3. remove the strings themselves

E.g., ideal output:

```
I want this
I want this
I want this
```

Any guidance on how to do this would be greatly appreciated.

I have tried a variety of solutions using awk and sed but have been unable to match only the text meeting all of the above conditions.

Comment: Can `"""` appear in some other context before a `match me` line or not? Is there always just 1 block to print or could there be multiple? If the latter what should be printed between them? Without seeing sample lines before and after the block of text you want printed it's a guess as to the best solution and any potential solution can't be tested adequately.

Comment: Remove first and last line: `sed '1d; $d; s/^ *//' file`

Comment: _ have tried a variety of solutions_ : So please show what you have tried, so that we can discuss why your solutions failed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using any POSIX awk:

```
$ awk '{sub(/^[[:space:]]+/,"")} f{if (/^"""/) f=0; else print} /^match me/{f=1}' file
I want this
I want this
I want this
```

I'm guessing at some of your requirements, see [my comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75796248/shell-selecting-matching-text-between-two-strings-on-different-lines/75796453#comment133704375_75796248). If there's only 1 such block in your input you could change `f=0` to `exit` for improved efficiency.

Answer (score 1):

Like this:

```
$ awk '/match/{p=1;next} /"""/{exit}p{sub(/ */, "")}p' file
I want this
I want this
I want this
```

Comment: Looks close but not quite right

        """misc text

        match this:
  Text I want

  Text I want

 """

 Text I dont want

With this command produces 0 matches

Comment: This is verbatim copy of your sample input and expected output. Be more clear

Comment: I am sorry for not being clearer. The goal was to match everything between some string (e.g., "match this") and the subsequent triple quote. Each occurrence or the first. With the ability for "match this" and the triple quote to appear on the same or different lines

Comment: @mlawsonca Regarding "...to appear on **the same or** different lines" in your comment: Your question subject says "selecting matching text between two strings **on different lines**" (emphasis mine in both quotes).  [The answer you accepted (mine)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75796453/1745001) won't work if `match me` and `"""` appear on the same line. You should ask a different question with more truly representative sample input/output and clearer requirements if you need help with THAT problem as it requires a quite different solution than the problem you asked about here.

Answer (score 1):

With GNU sed:

```
sed '/match me/,/"""/{/match me/d; /"""/d; s/^ *//}' file
```

Output:

```
I want this
I want this
I want this
```

Answer (score 1):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -n '/^\s*match me/{:a;n;/^\s*"""/b;p;ba}' file
```

Turn off implicit printing by setting `-n`.

Match white space at the beginning of a line followed by `match me` and then fetch the next line.

If the fetched line matches white space followed by `"""`, break out and perform no further processing.

Otherwise, print the current line and fetch the next and process as above.

N.B. The [n](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/sed.html#index-n-_0028next_002dline_0029-command) normally prints the current line and  fetches the next. However when used in conjunction with the `-n` option the printing is suppressed. Also control flow using the `b` command is explained [here](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/sed.html#Branching-and-flow-control).